# Removing metadata from Gmail sent through Email

Tags: perl, gmail

I am using this code to send Gmail from a perl script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail;

my ($mail,$error)=Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail->new( -smtp=>'smtp.gmail.com',
                                                 -login=>'xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
                                                 -pass=>'xxxxxxx');

#print "session error: $error" unless ($email!=-1);

$mail->send(-to=>'zzzzzz@gmail.com', -subject=>"Hello! there $name", -body=>'Just testing it',
            -attachments=>'full_path_to_file');

$mail->bye;
```

This code is inside an for loop and $name is the name of intended person. 
When I tested it I got some meta-data in my mail

```
Date: Fri, 12 Dec 2014 12:44:37 +0530
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

This doesn't happen if I use `'Hello'` as `-subject` . The `$name` variable is causing this . How can I remove the metadata from the mail ?

Comment: Could `$name` have a newline on the end of it?

Answer (score 0):

You could be facing [Image Blocking in HTML Email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/image-blocking/).